# Calling bash from python subprocess maintaining context, returning results and printing to screen

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, stdin, popen

I have a function that sends a statement to bash. It **prints the output in real time** to the console and also **returns the value**. It works flawlessly and looks like this:

```
def call_in_bash(statement): 
  process = subprocess.Popen(['bash','-c',statement],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)
  buffer = io.StringIO()
  selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()
  selector.register(process.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
  line = ''
  while process.poll() is None:
    events = selector.select()
    for key, mask in events:
      line = key.fileobj.readline()
      buffer.write(line)
      sys.stdout.write(line)

  selector.close()
  output = buffer.getvalue()
  buffer.close()
  return output
```

However, I'd like to make this a class with a constructor and a destructor so subsequent calls can **keep the context** until I destroy the object. That is, I can `call_in_bash("cd folder")` and then `call_in_bash("do something")` in that folder. To do so, I've tried to do something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
  self.process: Popen(['bash'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ...)

def call_to_bash(self, statement):
  self.process.stdin.write(statement + "\n")
  self.process.stdin.flush()
  
  # from here on same as before
```

It locks and **never finishes** no matter the command. I don't know what big of a difference it makes if I call `popen(['bash']` and then put stuff in its stdin instead of calling `bash -c statement`. In my mind they're pretty much the same thing but I'm clearly missing something important here. I have read lots of other questions and they address either keeping the context, returning the value or printing in real time, but never all three things at once.

Comment: The problem is that writing to a pipe causes most programs (including bash) to buffer their output. So you're not going to see the output from bash until the buffer is full and flushed or the bash process exits. The answer by Diego will cause bash to run interactively and line buffer its output. Some programs can also be told to not buffer their output (e.g., `python -U`) but I'm not aware of any way to get bash to unbuffer its output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to control and interactive shell with `pexpect`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pexpect
import sys

PROMPT = r"bash-5.2\$ "

c = pexpect.spawn("bash -i", encoding="utf-8")
c.logfile = sys.stdout
c.expect(PROMPT)
c.sendline("cd /tmp")
c.expect(PROMPT)
c.sendline("ls -l")
c.expect(PROMPT)
c.close()
```

Adapt it to your needs.